# Memory leak while doing canvas operations fillRect() through JavaScript.

Tags: javascript, browser, memory-leaks

When I try to run this particular test http://www.craftymind.com/factory/guimark3/vector/GM3_JS_Vector.html on our platform(CPU-MIPS5000 , RAM-1024MB) , I see that the test keeps on consuming memory at a high rate.Within  minutes it runs out of memory.Looking at the source code of the application, looks like fillRect is causing the issue.

Has anyone else faced the similar kind of issue?Any suggestion on this is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: everything is right. I didn't get that error.

Comment: On desktop it runs fine.We are running it on a low end device.

Comment: what operating system/browser/engine are you using?

Comment: linux/chrome/blink